# Trying to append terraform resources into one list but I am getting a syntax error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

My intention was to get it to make all the resources which are three lists and concat them into one list but I am getting this error here: Inappropriate value for attribute "resources": element 0: string required.

Here is what I tried:

```
`
resources = [
       concat(
          [for b in concat(each.value.local_data_bucket_write, each.value.local_data_bucket_read) : "arn:aws:s3:::${b}"],
          [for b in concat(each.value.local_data_bucket_write, each.value.local_data_bucket_read) : "arn:aws:s3:::${b}/*"],
          ["arn:aws:sts:${var.aws_region}:${var.data_aws_account_id}:*"]
        )
      ]`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression includes both surrounding brackets `[ ]` *and* a call to the `concat` function, which returns a list. Therefore your expression is producing an extra wrapping list, like this:

```
[
  [
    "arn:aws:s3:::example",
    "arn:aws:s3:::example/*",
    "arn:aws:sts:example:example:*",
  ],
]
```

Remove the surrounding `[ ]` brackets and instead assign the `concat` result directly to `resources`. That function result is naturally a list of strings, and so it will already be of a suitable type for an argument which expects a collection of strings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code has syntactical issue with an additional pair of `[ ]` in resources section.

Refer to [Specifying Multiple Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html#reference_policies_elements_resource_multiple-resources) in AWS IAM policies for more details.

[concat](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/concat) function already returns a list by combining multiple lists so correct code in your case should be

```
resources = concat(
          [for b in concat(each.value.local_data_bucket_write, each.value.local_data_bucket_read) : "arn:aws:s3:::${b}"],
          [for b in concat(each.value.local_data_bucket_write, each.value.local_data_bucket_read) : "arn:aws:s3:::${b}/*"],
          ["arn:aws:sts:${var.aws_region}:${var.data_aws_account_id}:*"]
        )
```